# Read lines from a text file containing dictionaries into elements of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a text file that looks like this

```
{'tableName': 'customer', 'type': 'VIEW'}
{'tableName': 'supplier', 'type': 'TABLE'}
{'tableName': 'owner', 'type': 'VIEW'}
```

I want to read it into a python program that stores it into a list of dictonaries like this

```
expectedOutput=[{'tableName': 'customer', 'type': 'VIEW'},{'tableName': 'supplier', 'type': 'TABLE'},{'tableName': 'owner', 'type': 'VIEW'}]
```

But the output I get is a list of strings

```
       output = ["{'tableName': 'customer', 'type': 'VIEW'}",
      "{'tableName': 'supplier', 'type': 'TABLE'}",
      "{'tableName': 'owner', 'type': 'VIEW'}"]
```

The code I run is

```
my_file3 = open("textFiles/python.txt", "r")
data3 = my_file3.read()
output = data3.split("\n")
```

Can someone show me how do I store the entries inside the list as dicts and not strings.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` but it can be dangerous (only do this if you trust the file):

```py
my_file3 = open("textFiles/python.txt") # specifying 'r' is unnecessary
data3 = my_file3.read()
output = [eval(line) for line in data3.splitlines()] # use splitlines() rather than split('\n')
```

If the file contains something like `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')` it could be very dangerous. Read the documentation for `eval` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

---

If you don't fully trust the file, use `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast
my_file3 = open("textFiles/python.txt")
data3 = my_file3.read()
output = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in data3.splitlines()]
```

This removes the risk - if the file contains something like an import, it will raise a `ValueError: malformed node or string`. Read the documentation for `ast.literal_eval` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

---

Output:

```py
[{'tableName': 'customer', 'type': 'VIEW'},
 {'tableName': 'supplier', 'type': 'TABLE'},
 {'tableName': 'owner', 'type': 'VIEW'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `json` module

```
import json
my_file3 = open("textFiles/python.txt", "r")
data3 = my_file3.read()
output = json.loads(str(data3.splitlines()))
print(output)
```

As Thonnu warned, `eval` is quite dangerous